# Position of drop down select material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, jsx

I am using select from material UI but the issue I'm facing the dropdown does not be in one position.

**How I want it:**

[image]

**How it's showing in mine:**

> when opening the dropdown

[image]

So basically the dropdown showing in the center of it's field rather than showing below it. I did my research and seen it is know to be default setting (to dropdown be below it's field) but not happening in my case.

**Code fo the dropdown**

```
 <div className="row-5" style={{ marginTop: "21px" }}>
                            <div className="repeat">

                                <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
                                    <InputLabel id="repeat-id">Repeat</InputLabel>
                                    <Select
                                        style={{ width: '420px' }}
                                        labelId="repeat-id"
                                        id="demo-simple-select-standard"
                                        // value={age}
                                        // onChange={handleChange}
                                        label="Repeat"
                                        defaultValue="Never"
                                    >
                                        <MenuItem value="Never">
                                            Never
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                                    </Select>
                                </FormControl>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/groupedselect-material-demo-forked-7d82g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must import the Select component from here :

```
    import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
    import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
```

that works for me very well.